# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' caused by split function

Tags: python-3.x

I have been moving some of my scripts from python 2.7 to python3 (3.6.8). While fixing one of my scripts, i am getting the error mentioned in subject line.

the part of the script where i am getting error at is as below.

```
info = conn.execute_command("Info")
lines = info.split('\n')
```

When i run this script i get an error copied below.

```
lines = info.split('\n')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I am trying to get lines split at '\n' in the response for info. However i am not sure what is the syntax here, to get rid of this error. Any suggestions...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `info` is a bytesstring, so what you should do is:

```
lines = info.split(b"\n")
```

But do note that lines would be a list of bytesstrings.

You could also do the following:

```
info = conn.execute_command("Info")
lines = info.decode("utf-8").split('\n')
```

then all the elements in `lines` will be normal strings.